# Why is drawLine offset by 1 pixel?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, paint

This is probably an easy one for Android experts.  I am trying to draw into a Bitmap via a Canvas.  I want exact colors, no anti-aliasing, and lines located at exact absolute coordinates within the Bitmap.  Sometimes the lines are in the correct position and sometimes they are offset by 1 pixel.  I have a feeling this has something to do with scaling.  But I'm not sure.  Here's the code:

```
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Paint.WHITE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
    mPaint.setDither(false);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    drawingContext.mycanvas.drawLine(20, 0, 10, 10, mPaint);
```

This actually draws a line from (19,0) to (10,9).  Why?

Comment: I believe that draw line strokes such that the stroked line is split by the defined line.

Meaning, if you draw a line with coordinates 2,2 x 10,2 with stroke width of 2, you end up with a rectangle of 1,2,10,3 (left,top,right bottom).  

I'm not sure how this "framing" works if strokewidth is set to 1, but this sort of thing is likely responsible for the error.

Comment: It probably does that for the same reason that the OpenGL coordinate space is often inverted compared to any normal coordinate space; graphics programmers are all just slightly crazy.  In other words, ab11's explanation is probably correct.

Comment: My first concern is that drawLine() takes floating point parameters. That was unexpected but I think it has to do with Android's mission to run on any screen. So what's the work-around?? I need to turn on specific pixels on my display (which is an embedded system, not a phone so I don't care about scaling).

Comment: I had to give up on this and write a Bresenham algorithm, setting pixels one by one.  That works OK for what I'm doing.  I suspect a drawLine bug when drawing left to right, bottom to top lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer.  I had to give up on this and write a Bresenham algorithm, setting pixels one by one. That works OK for what I'm doing. I suspect a drawLine bug when drawing left to right, bottom to top lines.